# How to multiply all terms of a fraction by something in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equation:

```
u = -J/4 + (J*exp(-J*β) + bz*(-exp(bz*β) + exp(-bz*β)))/(exp(bz*β) + 1 + exp(-bz*β) + exp(-J*β))
```

The fraction part is this:

```
(J*exp(-J*β) + bz*(-exp(bz*β) + exp(-bz*β)))/(exp(bz*β) + 1 + exp(-bz*β) + exp(-J*β))
```

I'm trying to multiply the fraction by `exp(-bz*β)` in both the numerator and the denominator to get this exactly

```
u = -J/4 + (J*exp(-(J+bz)*β) + bz*(-1 + exp(-2*bz*β)))/(1 + exp(-bz*β) + exp(-2*bz*β) + exp(-(J+bz)*β))
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`epath` might be able to help with this but I would just take the expression apart and put it back together:

```
>>> eq.args
(-J/4, (J*exp(-J*ß) + bz*(-exp(bz*ß) + exp(-bz*ß)))/(exp(bz*ß) + 1 + exp(-bz*ß)
+ exp(-J*ß)))
>>> j, f = _
>>> c = exp(-bz*β)
>>> n, d = fraction(f)
>>> powsimp(expand(c*n))/(powsimp(expand(c*d)))
(J*exp(-ß*(J + bz)) - bz + bz*exp(-2*bz*ß))/(exp(-J*ß - bz*ß) + 1 + exp(-bz*ß) +
 exp(-2*bz*ß))
>>> collect(_,bz)
(J*exp(-ß*(J + bz)) + bz*(-1 + exp(-2*bz*ß)))/(exp(-J*ß - bz*ß) + 1 + exp(-bz*ß)
 + exp(-2*bz*ß))
>>> factor_terms(_)
(J*exp(-ß*(J + bz)) + bz*(-1 + exp(-2*bz*ß)))/(1 + exp(-ß*(J + bz)) + exp(-bz*ß)
 + exp(-2*bz*ß))
>>> j + _
-J/4 + (J*exp(-ß*(J + bz)) + bz*(-1 + exp(-2*bz*ß)))/(1 + exp(-ß*(J + bz)) + exp
(-bz*ß) + exp(-2*bz*ß))
```

Note the use of `expand(c*n)/expand(c*d)` -- without expansion, the `c` will cancel out automatically in the ratio.